# In Google Cloud Platform, Is there a any service to be a replacement of Web server (Nginx Or Apache) and Load Balancer(Haproxy)

Tags: google-compute-engine

RightNow, I am manging URL's and its redirection using Nginx hosted on physical machine. URL Redirection is achieved and pointed to different load balancers(Haproxy) as mentioned in the vhost file of Nginx.
Is there any option available in GCP to provide the services of redirection without using Nginx and Apache?  And also let me know what are the alternate options available in GCP for Haproxy

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have a few services (and maybe some static content) serving via Haproxy (which is doing load balancing) to the Internet.

Based on that I assume that if someone wants to go to "yourservice.com/example1" would be redirected by load balancer to service1, and if someone types "yourservice.com/static1" them he will be served static content by different service etc.

GCP has exactly a service you're asking for which can do url/content based load balancing. You can also move your current services to the Google Compute Engine (as virtual machines) or Google Kubernetes Engine which will run your services as a containers.

Also - using GCE or GKE can do autoscaling if that's what you need.

Load balancing provided by the GCP can do all the content based balancing that Haproxy which you're using now.

If you're using some internal load balancing now, I believe it could also be done with one load balancer ( and could simplify your configuration (just some VM or containers running your services and one load balancer).

You can read more about [load balancing concepts](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/) and [specifically about setting up GCP to do that.](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https)